# jquery long-poll not displaying anything

Tags: jquery, long-polling

For some reason the following is not displaying anything at all - any idea what I did wrong?

UPDATE 1:

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: \"getDbData.php\", success: function(data){
      document.write(data.timestamp);
    }, dataType: \"json\", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
  })();
});
```

getDbData.php

```
$response = array();
$response['timestamp'] = time()+microtime();
echo json_encode($response);
sleep(1);
```

---

ORIGINAL CODE:

index.php

```
<?php

echo "
<html>
<head>

<script src=\"jquery.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  (function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: \"getDbData.php\", success: function(data){
      var json = eval('('+data+')');
      if json['timestamp'] != \"\" {
        document.write(json['timestamp']);
      }, dataType: \"json\", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
    })();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

"; //end of echo
?>
```

getDbData.php

```
<?php
  $response = array();

  for ($testLoop=0; $testLoop < 100; $testLoop++) {
    $response['timestamp'] = time()+microtime();
    echo json_encode($response);
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong with this...

Comment: ajax requests don't "complete" until the request is complete, in your case the request takes 100 seconds to complete so it will always hit the 30 second timeout.

Comment: I removed the for loop and still no output...?

Comment: Most likely you're hitting the error handler due to invalid json. Once you stop hitting the error handler by returning valid json, it will fail on this line `var json = eval('('+data+')');` because `data` is already parsed as an object, it isn't a json string.

Comment: So any solution for how to display the data object then? I tried document.write(data.timestamp); but that still no output.

Comment: as written, you'll never get to that line. have you modified it at all?

Comment: Yes I did change the code, yet still no output (see code update above).